# trying to test the vulnerability CVE 2015-0205 for university project

Tags: tls, vulnerability, cve, exposure

I'm trying to establish a TLS client-server connection with openssl 1.0.1x on ubuntu-14.04 in order to create a fix for CVE-2015-0205 for learning purposes.

I found this explanation of CVE-2015-0205:

> An OpenSSL server will accept a DH certificate for client
> authentication without the certificate verify message. This
> effectively allows a client to authenticate without the use of a
> private key. This only affects servers which trust a client
> certificate authority which issues certificates containing DH keys:
> these are extremely rare and hardly ever encountered. This issue was
> reported to OpenSSL on 22nd October 2014 by Karthikeyan Bhargavan of
> the PROSECCO team at INRIA. The fix was developed by Stephen Henson of
> the OpenSSL core team.

And another explanation:

> Attacking OpenSSL In the OpenSSL server, the ClientCertificateVerify
> message is properly expected whenever a client certificate has been
> presented, except when the client sends a static Diffie-Hellman
> certificate. The motivation behind this design is that, in static DH
> ciphersuites, the client is allowed to authenticate the key exchange
> by using the static DH key sent in the ClientCertificate; in this
> case, the client then skips both the ClientKeyExchange and
> ClientCertificateVerify messages. However, because of a bug in
> OpenSSL, client authentication can be bypassed in two cases by
> confusing the static and ephemeral state machine composite
> implementation. In both the static DH and ephemeral DHE key exchanges,
> the attacker M can send an honest user u’s static DH certificate, then
> send its own ephemeral keys in a ClientKeyExchange and skip the
> ClientCertificateVerify. The server will use the ephemeral keys from
> the ClientKeyExchange (ignoring those in the certificate), and will
> report u’s identity to the application. Consequently, an attacker is
> able to impersonate the owner of any static Diffie-Hellman certificate
> at any OpenSSL server.

So, I worked towards a cryptodata setup required in order to start TLS connection:

For server certificate and key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

For the client, I generated a DH key pair, with the OpenSSL command-line tool :

```
  openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
  openssl genpkey -paramfile dhparam.pem -out dhkey.pem
```

then created the public key :

```
  openssl pkey -in dhkey.pem -pubout -out dhpubkey.pem
```

then I created a CSR.file:

CSRs are self signed which obviously can't be done for DH because DH is not a signing algorithm. But i created one anyway for a different key (one that can sign, e.g. RSA). To create an RSA key and an
associated CSR:

```
  openssl genrsa -out rsakey.pem 2048

  openssl req -new -key rsakey.pem -out rsa.csr
```

then:

generate the DH cert from the RSA CSR and the DH public key. It is not possible to create a self signed DH cert because (as noted above) DH is not a signing algorithm.
Therefore i have set up a CA certificate/key, with this guide:

https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/#becoming-certificate-authority

and finally obtained the dhcert with this command:

```
  openssl x509 -req -in rsa.csr -CAkey myCA.key -CA myCA.pem -force_pubkey dhpubkey.pem -out dhcert.pem -CAcreateserial
```

So, i forced the dhparamethers on the server and providing CApath, cert.pem and key.pem created before with this command(opensslx stands for vulnerable version):
[image]

then I started it :

[image]

then I used this command for the client, forcing the ciphersuite I need for trying the vulnerability, otherwise it would've start ECDH, you can see here :
[image]

then i started it :
[image]

but the server returns a `peer did not return a certificate` error (notice that I used the `-verify_return_error common` that closes my TLS section if any error occurred):
[image]

like the client cert won't be received/be sent, can you explain why?

Comment: So, this queston is just about the error you received? How is the CVE explanation relevant to the error?

Comment: I created the dh certificate containing dh key like expressed in cve becouse the server will autenticate the client without the use of a private key, but for some reason the client won't send the certificate to the server, so i don't get the tls step protocol I need to test the vulnerability